# Python "data naming"

Tags: python

My input:

**test_set**, like:

```
[['4.5', '6', 'U1'], ['5', '5', 'U1'], ['5', '7', 'U1'], ['7', '6.5', 'U1'], ['5.5', '5.5', 'U2'], ['5.5', '7.5', 'U2']]
```

---

After this I made a lot of calculation with this data, and my "final" result is **array** of **test_set_final**

```
test_set_final=array([[ 1.6488378 ],
       [ 2.61782463],
       [ 0.62126043],
       [ 1.00322042],
       [ 2.08938831],
       [ 0.09282412]])
```

---

Now what I want to do is for `test_set_final`, add **class name** which is "stored" in last place of **test_set**, so that result will look, for example for test_set_final:

```
test_set_final=[['1.6488378' , 'U1'],['2.61782463' , 'U1'],['0.62126043' , 'U1'],['1.00322042' , 'U1'],['2.08938831' , 'U2'],,['0.09282412' , 'U2']]
```

---

This "test_set" data is random data and have random name of "classes", but always on last place after comma....

Comment: Am I hallucinating or did this exact question pop up a few times (propably by the same user) and the previous instances are now gone?

Comment: @delnan: No, but I think after I told him to be more concise on an older (and much longer) version of this question he gave it another try.

Comment: Yes, question before was little confused too longer for understand...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it (had it prepared from the last version of your question):

```
test_set_final = [[r, c[-1]] for [r], c in zip (test_set_final, test_set)]
```

**Edit:** Added unpacking for `r` - the example looked different before.

Comment: I agree, but suggest to thaking to maybe replace `c[2]` with `c[-1]` if the class name is always the last variable in each row of `test_set`, but not always the second variable counting from zero.  `c[2]` says its always the second (counting from zero).